# How Spring Security Filter Chain works

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, filter, jwt

I realize that Spring security build on chain of filters, which will intercept the request, detect (absence of) authentication, redirect to authentication entry point or pass the request to authorization service, and eventually let the request either hit the servlet or throw security exception (unauthenticated or unauthorized). *DelegatingFitlerProxy* glues these filters together. To perform their tasks, these filter access services such as *UserDetailsService* and *AuthenticationManager*.

Key filters in the chain are (in the order)

- SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (restores Authentication from JSESSIONID)
- UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (performs authentication)
- ExceptionTranslationFilter (catch security exceptions from FilterSecurityInterceptor)
- FilterSecurityInterceptor (may throw authentication and authorization exceptions)

I'm confused how these filters are used. Is it that for the spring provided form-login, *UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter* is only used for */login*, and latter filters are not? Does the *form-login* namespace element auto-configure these filters? Does every request (authenticated or not) reach *FilterSecurityInterceptor* for non-login url?

**What if I want to secure my REST API with *JWT-token*, which is retrieved from login?** I must configure two namespace configuration `http` tags, rights? One for */login* with `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, and another one for REST url's, with custom `JwtAuthenticationFilter`.

Does configuring two `http` elements create two `springSecurityFitlerChains`? Is `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` turned off by default, until I declare `form-login`? How do I replace `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` with a filter which will obtain `Authentication` from existing `JWT-token` rather than `JSESSIONID`?

Comment: The default order of filters is defined in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.FilterComparator

Answer (score 301, accepted):

The Spring security filter chain is a very complex and flexible engine.

> Key filters in the chain are (in the order)
>
> - SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (restores Authentication from JSESSIONID)
> - UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (performs authentication)
> - ExceptionTranslationFilter (catch security exceptions from FilterSecurityInterceptor)
> - FilterSecurityInterceptor (may throw authentication and authorization exceptions)

Looking at the [current stable release 4.2.1 documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/), section [13.3 Filter Ordering](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#filter-ordering) you could see the whole filter chain's filter organization:

> 13.3 Filter Ordering
>
> The order that filters are defined in the chain is very important.
>   Irrespective of which filters you are actually using, the order should
>   be as follows:
>
> 1. ***ChannelProcessingFilter***, because it might need to redirect to a different protocol
> 2. ***SecurityContextPersistenceFilter***, so a SecurityContext can be set up in the SecurityContextHolder at the beginning of a web request, and
>      any changes to the SecurityContext can be copied to the HttpSession
>      when the web request ends (ready for use with the next web request)
> 3. ***ConcurrentSessionFilter***, because it uses the SecurityContextHolder functionality and needs to update the SessionRegistry to reflect ongoing requests from the principal
> 4. Authentication processing mechanisms - 
>      ***UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter***, ***CasAuthenticationFilter***,
>      ***BasicAuthenticationFilter*** etc - so that the SecurityContextHolder can
>      be modified to contain a valid Authentication request token
> 5. The ***SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter***, if you are using it to install a Spring Security aware HttpServletRequestWrapper into your
>      servlet container
> 6. The ***JaasApiIntegrationFilter***, if a *JaasAuthenticationToken* is in the SecurityContextHolder this will process the FilterChain as the
>      Subject in the JaasAuthenticationToken
> 7. ***RememberMeAuthenticationFilter***, so that if no earlier authentication processing mechanism updated the SecurityContextHolder,
>      and the request presents a cookie that enables remember-me services to
>      take place, a suitable remembered Authentication object will be put
>      there
> 8. ***AnonymousAuthenticationFilter***, so that if no earlier authentication processing mechanism updated the SecurityContextHolder,
>      an anonymous Authentication object will be put there
> 9. ***ExceptionTranslationFilter***, to catch any Spring Security exceptions so that either an HTTP error response can be returned or an
>      appropriate AuthenticationEntryPoint can be launched
> 10. ***FilterSecurityInterceptor***, to protect web URIs and raise exceptions when access is denied

Now, I'll try to go on by your questions one by one:

> I'm confused how these filters are used. Is it that for the spring
>   provided form-login, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter is only used
>   for /login, and latter filters are not? Does the form-login namespace
>   element auto-configure these filters? Does every request
>   (authenticated or not) reach FilterSecurityInterceptor for non-login
>   url?

Once you are configuring a `<security-http>` section, for each one you must at least provide one authentication mechanism. This must be one of the filters which match group 4 in the 13.3 Filter Ordering section from the Spring Security documentation I've just referenced.

This is the minimum valid security:http element which can be configured:

```
<security:http authentication-manager-ref="mainAuthenticationManager" 
               entry-point-ref="serviceAccessDeniedHandler">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/sectest/zone1/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
</security:http>
```

Just doing it, these filters are configured in the filter chain proxy:

```
{
        "1": "org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter",
        "2": "org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter",
        "3": "org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter",
        "4": "org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter",
        "5": "org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter",
        "6": "org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter",
        "7": "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter",
        "8": "org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter",
        "9": "org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter",
        "10": "org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor"
    }
```

Note: I get them by creating a simple RestController which @Autowires the FilterChainProxy and returns it's contents:

```
    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy filterChainProxy;

    @Override
    @RequestMapping("/filterChain")
    public @ResponseBody Map<Integer, Map<Integer, String>> getSecurityFilterChainProxy(){
        return this.getSecurityFilterChainProxy();
    }

    public Map<Integer, Map<Integer, String>> getSecurityFilterChainProxy(){
        Map<Integer, Map<Integer, String>> filterChains= new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, String>>();
        int i = 1;
        for(SecurityFilterChain secfc :  this.filterChainProxy.getFilterChains()){
            //filters.put(i++, secfc.getClass().getName());
            Map<Integer, String> filters = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
            int j = 1;
            for(Filter filter : secfc.getFilters()){
                filters.put(j++, filter.getClass().getName());
            }
            filterChains.put(i++, filters);
        }
        return filterChains;
    }
```

Here we could see that just by declaring the `<security:http>` element with one minimum configuration, all the default filters are included, but none of them is of a Authentication type (4th group in 13.3 Filter Ordering section). So it actually means that just by declaring the `security:http` element, the SecurityContextPersistenceFilter, the ExceptionTranslationFilter and the FilterSecurityInterceptor are auto-configured.

In fact, one authentication processing mechanism should be configured, and even security namespace beans processing claims for that, throwing an error during startup, but it can be bypassed adding an entry-point-ref attribute in `<http:security>`

If I add a basic `<form-login>` to the configuration, this way:

```
<security:http authentication-manager-ref="mainAuthenticationManager">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/sectest/zone1/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <security:form-login />
</security:http>
```

Now, the filterChain will be like this:

```
{
        "1": "org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter",
        "2": "org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter",
        "3": "org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter",
        "4": "org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter",
        "5": "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter",
        "6": "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter",
        "7": "org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter",
        "8": "org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter",
        "9": "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter",
        "10": "org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter",
        "11": "org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter",
        "12": "org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor"
    }
```

Now, this two filters [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#form-login-filter) and org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter are created and configured in the FilterChainProxy.

So, now, the questions:

> Is it that for the spring provided form-login,
>   UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter is only used for /login, and
>   latter filters are not?

Yes, it is used to try to complete a login processing mechanism in case the request matches the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter url. This url can be configured or even changed it's behaviour to match every request.

You could too have more than one Authentication processing mechanisms configured in the same FilterchainProxy (such as HttpBasic, CAS, etc).

> Does the form-login namespace element auto-configure these filters?

No, the form-login element configures the UsernamePasswordAUthenticationFilter, and in case you don't provide a login-page url, it also configures the org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter, which ends in a simple autogenerated login page.

The other filters are auto-configured by default just by creating a `<security:http>` element with no `security:"none"` attribute.

> Does every request (authenticated or not) reach FilterSecurityInterceptor for non-login url?

Every request should reach it, as it is the element which takes care of whether the request has the rights to reach the requested url. But some of the filters processed before might stop the filter chain processing just not calling `FilterChain.doFilter(request, response);`. For example, a CSRF filter might stop the filter chain processing if the request has not the csrf parameter.

> What if I want to secure my REST API with JWT-token, which is retrieved from login? I must configure two namespace configuration http tags, rights? Other one for /login with `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, and another one for REST url's, with custom `JwtAuthenticationFilter`.

No, you are not forced to do this way. You could declare both `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` and the `JwtAuthenticationFilter` in the same http element, but it depends on the concrete behaviour of each of this filters. Both approaches are possible, and which one to choose finnally depends on own preferences.

> Does configuring two http elements create two springSecurityFitlerChains?

Yes, that's true

> Is UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter turned off by default, until I declare form-login?

Yes, you could see it in the filters raised in each one of the configs I posted

> How do I replace SecurityContextPersistenceFilter with one, which will obtain Authentication from existing JWT-token rather than JSESSIONID?

You could avoid SecurityContextPersistenceFilter, just configuring [session strategy](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-web) in `<http:element>`. Just configure like this:

`<security:http create-session="stateless" >`

Or, In this case you could overwrite it with another filter, this way inside the `<security:http>` element:

```
<security:http ...>  
   <security:custom-filter ref="myCustomFilter" position="SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER"/>    
</security:http>
<beans:bean id="myCustomFilter" class="com.xyz.myFilter" />
```

EDIT:

> One question about "You could too have more than one Authentication processing mechanisms configured in the same FilterchainProxy". Will the latter overwrite the authentication performed by first one, if declaring multiple (Spring implementation) authentication filters? How this relates to having multiple authentication providers?

This finally depends on the implementation of each filter itself, but it's true the fact that the latter authentication filters at least are able to overwrite any prior authentication eventually made by preceding filters.

But this won't necesarily happen. I have some production cases in secured REST services where I use a kind of authorization token which can be provided both as a Http header or inside the request body. So I configure two filters which recover that token, in one case from the Http Header and the other from the request body of the own rest request. It's true the fact that if one http request provides that authentication token both as Http header and inside the request body, both filters will try to execute the authentication mechanism delegating it to the manager, but it could be easily avoided simply checking if the request is already authenticated just at the begining of the `doFilter()` method of each filter.

Having more than one authentication filter is related to having more than one authentication providers, but don't force it. In the case I exposed before, I have two authentication filter but I only have one authentication provider, as both of the filters create the same type of Authentication object so in both cases the authentication manager delegates it to the same provider.

And opposite to this, I too have a scenario where I publish just one UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter but the user credentials both can be contained in DB or LDAP, so I have two UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken supporting providers, and the AuthenticationManager delegates any authentication attempt from the filter to the providers secuentially to validate the credentials.

So, I think it's clear that neither the amount of authentication filters determine the amount of authentication providers nor the amount of provider determine the amount of filters.

> Also, documentation states SecurityContextPersistenceFilter is responsible of cleaning the SecurityContext, which is important due thread pooling. If I omit it or provide custom implementation, I have to implement the cleaning manually, right? Are there more similar gotcha's when customizing the chain?

I did not look carefully into this filter before, but after your last question I've been checking it's implementation, and as usually in Spring, nearly everything could be configured, extended or overwrited.

The [SecurityContextPersistenceFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/context/SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java) delegates in a [SecurityContextRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/context/SecurityContextRepository.java) implementation the search for the SecurityContext. By default, a [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/context/HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java) is used, but this could be changed using one of the constructors of the filter. So it may be better to write an SecurityContextRepository which fits your needs and just configure it in the SecurityContextPersistenceFilter, trusting in it's proved behaviour rather than start making all from scratch.

Comment: This was enlightening explanation. One question about "You could too have more than one Authentication processing mechanisms configured in the same FilterchainProxy". Will the latter overwrite the authentication performed by first one, if declaring multiple (Spring implementation) authentication filters? How this relates to having multiple authentication providers?

Comment: Also, documentation states SecurityContextPersistenceFilter is responsible of cleaning the SecurityContext, which is important due thread pooling. If I omit it or provide custom implementation, I have to implement the cleaning manually, right? Are there more similar gotcha's when customizing the chain?

Comment: @TuomasToivonen I edited my answer after the questions in your last comments

Comment: @jlumietu There is a missing quote in the java annotation next to _("/filterChain)_. Also where do you place this method? I have tried to add it in a controller and I have : `No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

Comment: @BigDong make sure you have declared the SpringSecurityFilterChain in both web.xml or java webapp config and in your spring configuration. This code snippet must be included in a Controller, just as you did. And yes, you are wright about the missing quote

Comment: @jlumietu I am not using xml configuration. How do I declare it in Java Config ? isn't it automatically configured on boot when I added in my configuration a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` ?

Comment: @BigDong, It's difficult to say without seeing your configuration, but it should be enough with your configuration, no matter is xml based or java based. And in your web.xml or `WebApplicationInitializer`, you should have declared the filter as well

Comment: That was an explanation worth every word. For new users, who want more insights into Spring Security basics, see this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67329660/basics-of-spring-security/67331836#67331836

Answer (score 39):

Spring security is a filter based framework, it plants a WALL(HttpFireWall) before your application in terms of proxy filters or spring managed beans. Your request has to pass through multiple filters to reach your API.

#### Sequence of execution in Spring Security

1. **`WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter`** Provides integration between the SecurityContext and Spring Web's WebAsyncManager.
2. **`SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`** This filter will only execute once per request, Populates the SecurityContextHolder with information obtained from the configured SecurityContextRepository prior to the request and stores it back in the repository once the request has completed and clearing the context holder.
   *Request is checked for existing session. If new request, SecurityContext will be created else if request has session then existing security-context will be obtained from respository*.
3. **`HeaderWriterFilter`** Filter implementation to add headers to the current response.
4. **`LogoutFilter`** If request url is `/logout`(for default configuration) or if request url matches `RequestMatcher` configured in `LogoutConfigurer` then

- clears security context.
- invalidates the session
- deletes all the cookies with cookie names configured in `LogoutConfigurer`
- Redirects to default logout success url  `/` or logout success url configured or invokes logoutSuccessHandler configured.

5. **`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`**

- For any request url other than loginProcessingUrl this filter will not process further but filter chain just continues.
- If requested URL is matches(must be `HTTP POST`) default `/login` or matches `.loginProcessingUrl()` configured in `FormLoginConfigurer` then `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` attempts authentication.
- default login form parameters are username and password, can be overridden by `usernameParameter(String)`, `passwordParameter(String)`.
- setting `.loginPage()` [overrides defaults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apOKt.png)
- While attempting authentication

  - an [`Authentication`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TQS8.png) object(`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` or any implementation of `Authentication` in case of your custom auth filter) is created.
  - and `authenticationManager.authenticate(authToken)` will be invoked
  - Note that we can configure any number of `AuthenticationProvider` authenticate method tries all auth providers and checks any of the auth provider ***`supports`*** authToken/authentication object, supporting auth provider will be used for authenticating. and returns Authentication object in case of successful authentication else throws `AuthenticationException`.
- If authentication success session will be created and `authenticationSuccessHandler` will be invoked which redirects to the target url configured(default is `/`)
- If authentication failed user becomes un-authenticated user and chain continues.

6. `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter`, if you are using it to install a Spring Security aware HttpServletRequestWrapper into your servlet container
7. `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` Detects if there is no Authentication object in the SecurityContextHolder, if no authentication object found, creates `Authentication` object (`AnonymousAuthenticationToken`) with granted authority `ROLE_ANONYMOUS`. Here `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` facilitates identifying un-authenticated users subsequent requests.

##### **<sub>Debug logs</sub>**

```
DEBUG - /app/admin/app-config at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@aeef7b36: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
```

8. `ExceptionTranslationFilter`, to catch any Spring Security exceptions so that either an HTTP error response can be returned or an appropriate AuthenticationEntryPoint can be launched
9. `FilterSecurityInterceptor`
   There will be `FilterSecurityInterceptor` which comes almost last in the filter chain which gets Authentication object from `SecurityContext` and gets granted authorities list(roles granted) and it will make a decision whether to allow this request to reach the requested resource or not, decision is made by matching with the allowed `AntMatchers` configured in `HttpSecurityConfiguration`.

Consider the exceptions 401-UnAuthorized and 403-Forbidden. These decisions will be done at the last in the filter chain

- Un authenticated user trying to access public resource - **Allowed**
- Un authenticated user trying to access secured resource - **401-UnAuthorized**
- Authenticated user trying to access restricted resource(restricted for his role) - **403-Forbidden**

---

Note: User Request flows not only in above mentioned filters, but there are others filters too not shown here.(`ConcurrentSessionFilter`,`RequestCacheAwareFilter`,`SessionManagementFilter` ...) 
It will be different when you use your custom auth filter instead of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`.
It will be different if you configure JWT auth filter and omit `.formLogin() i.e, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` it will become entirely different case.

---

Just For reference. Filters in spring-web and spring-security
Note: **refer package name in pic**, as there are some other filters from orm and my custom implemented filter.

[image]

> [From Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/HttpSecurityBuilder.html#addFilter-javax.servlet.Filter-) ordering of filters is given as

> - ChannelProcessingFilter

- ConcurrentSessionFilter
- SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
- LogoutFilter
- X509AuthenticationFilter
- AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter
- CasAuthenticationFilter
- UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
- ConcurrentSessionFilter
- OpenIDAuthenticationFilter
- DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter
- DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter
- ConcurrentSessionFilter
- DigestAuthenticationFilter
- BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter
- BasicAuthenticationFilter
- RequestCacheAwareFilter
- SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
- JaasApiIntegrationFilter
- RememberMeAuthenticationFilter
- AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
- SessionManagementFilter
- ExceptionTranslationFilter
- FilterSecurityInterceptor
- SwitchUserFilter

You can also refer
[most common way to authenticate a modern web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58404641/2825798) 
[difference between authentication and authorization in context of Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58352649/2825798)

Comment: well taken, from where do these additional filters come in as in the `Sequence of execution in Spring Security` there are only 9 filters listed ? could you comment?

Comment: long before i was going through source code of spring security in my eclipse. I didn't get much docs related to this. Max i referred to this https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/HttpSecurityBuilder.html#addFilter-javax.servlet.Filter-

Comment: How can we apply form field validation at level 5, semantically using spring validation?

Answer (score 5):

> `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` is only used for `/login`, and latter filters are not?

No, `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` extends `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`, and this contains a `RequestMatcher`, that means you can define your own processing url, this filter only handle the `RequestMatcher` matches the request url, the default processing url is `/login`.

Later filters can still handle the request, if the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` executes `chain.doFilter(request, response);`.

More details about [core fitlers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-web-filters.html)

> Does the form-login namespace element auto-configure these filters?

`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` is created by `<form-login>`, these are [Standard Filter Aliases and Ordering](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.7.RELEASE/reference/ns-config.html#filter-stack)

> Does every request (authenticated or not) reach FilterSecurityInterceptor for non-login url?

It depends on whether the before fitlers are successful, but `FilterSecurityInterceptor` is the last fitler normally.

> Does configuring two http elements create two springSecurityFitlerChains?

Yes, every fitlerChain has a `RequestMatcher`, if the `RequestMatcher` matches the request, the request will be handled by the fitlers in the fitler chain.

The default `RequestMatcher` matches all request if you don't config the pattern, or you can config the specific url (`<http pattern="/rest/**"`).

If you want to konw more about the fitlers, I think you can check source code in spring security.
`doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)`