# What is the difference between authentication and authorization in context of Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, authorization

I'm working on a java spring boot project which I'm trying to get spring security set up for user authentication with JWT, the tutorial I'm following(and also many tutorials and projects I found on the internet) talks about two sections- **authentication and authorization**.

In most tutorials there are two filter classes one handles Authentication, and the other handles Authorization! 
(Some I have found with only one class which extends *`OncePerRequestFilter`* class).

In those projects that have two filter classes, 
The Authentication filter class extends *`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`* class.
Authorization class extends *`BasicAuthenticationFilter`* class.

Is there a way that I can only use authentication part in my project or should I use both classes to set up user authentication in spring security?

Any explanation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way that I can only use authentication part in my project or should I use both classes to set up user authentication in spring security?

No, there is no concept of only authentication part, you have wrong perception about spring security, spring security is all about configuration either by using default or by implementing your custom configurations. (`AuthenticationFilters`, `AuthenticationProviders`, `AuthenticationToken` etc)

---

Spring security is all about authentication and authorization, Spring security is configured by declaring a filter DelegatingFilterProxy in web.xml(In Spring boot it will be done by auto configuration).

Spring security puts a **WALL**(***HttpFireWall***) before your application in terms of proxy filters or spring managed beans. Request can reach your application if it succeeds in both authentication and authorization part.

#### 1. Authentication is all about identification of user.

it will undergoes

- validation of credentials or
- validating authorization header content or
- validating cookie associated with request (JSESSIONID cookie) i.e, session
- If none of the above matches user is identified as Anonymous.

Here in this step [**`Authentication`**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TQS8.png)  object will be created. From auth object you can get

- **details object** (additional details about the authentication request)
- **principal object** (`UserDetails` or `AuthenticatedPrincipal` or `Principal`)
- **credentials**(usually password, but could be anything relevant to the `AuthenticationManager`)
- collection of **grantedAuthorites**
- and a boolean **authenticated**.

#### 2. Authorization is all about access decision.

There will be `FilterSecurityInterceptor` which comes almost last in the filter chain which gets `Authentication` object from `SecurityContext` and gets granted authorities list(roles granted) and it will make a decision whether to allow this request to reach the requested resource or not, decision is made by matching with the allowed AntMatchers configured in `HttpSecurityConfiguration`.

Consider the exceptions 401-UnAuthorized and 403-Forbidden. These decisions will be done at the last in the filter chain
**401-UnAuthorized**: Un authenticated user trying to access secured resource.
**403-Forbidden** : Authenticated user trying to access restricted resource.
Un authenticated user will be allowed to access non restricted resources and he will not get UnAuthorized error but it is handled by `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` which sets authority `ROLE_ANONYMOUS` for unauthenticated user.

<sub>**Note**</sub>
Below given filter ordering. where,
Authentication is @order-4
Authorization is @Order-9(Last)

> **From Doc**
>   Spring Security has several areas where patterns you have defined are tested against incoming requests in order to decide how the request should be handled. This occurs when the `FilterChainProxy` decides which filter chain a request should be passed through and also when the `FilterSecurityInterceptor` decides which security constraints apply to a request. It's important to understand what the mechanism is and what URL value is used when testing against the patterns that you define.
>   **Filter Ordering**
>   The order that filters are defined in the chain is very important. Irrespective of which filters you are actually using, the order should be as follows:
>   1. **`ChannelProcessingFilter`**, because it might need to redirect to a different protocol
>   2. **`SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`**, so a SecurityContext can be set up in the SecurityContextHolder at the beginning of a web request, and any changes to the SecurityContext can be copied to the `HttpSession` when the web request ends (ready for use with the next web request)
>   3. **`ConcurrentSessionFilter`**, because it uses the `SecurityContextHolder` functionality but needs to update the `SessionRegistry` to reflect ongoing requests from the principal
>   4. **Authentication processing mechanisms** - `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, CasAuthenticationFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter etc - so that the SecurityContextHolder can be modified to contain a valid Authentication request token
>   5. **The `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter`**, if you are using it to install a Spring Security aware `HttpServletRequestWrapper` into your servlet container
>   6. **`RememberMeAuthenticationFilter`**, so that if no earlier authentication processing mechanism updated the `SecurityContextHolder`, and the request presents a cookie that enables remember-me services to take place, a suitable remembered Authentication object will be put there
>   7. **`AnonymousAuthenticationFilter`**, so that if no earlier authentication processing mechanism updated the `SecurityContextHolder`, an anonymous Authentication object will be put there
>   8. **`ExceptionTranslationFilter`**, to catch any Spring Security exceptions so that either an HTTP error response can be returned or an appropriate `AuthenticationEntryPoint` can be launched
>   9. **`FilterSecurityInterceptor`**, to protect web URIs and raise exceptions when access is denied

<sub>**Just to give some idea of filters in spring security**</sub>

[image]

<sub>Finally, if you are new to spring security. My suggestion is to try out maximum examples and spend more time on debug logs and try to understand the flow.</sub>

Comment: @Hasintha Abeykoon You can try out working examples from [my git hub repository](https://github.com/nlpraveennl/springsecurity). Try only first 10 examples first. There are very few examples for spring boot. Recommend you to try non spring boot projects too that will give basic idea which spring boot projects won't give.

Answer (score -1):

#### u have to write ur userDetial to tell spring current user authorization and config that

```
public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private User user;

public MyUserDetails(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return user.getLogin();
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return user.getPassword();
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return user.getGrantedAuthorities();
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return user.getActivated();
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return user.getActivated();
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return user.getActivated();
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return user.getActivated();
}

}
```

#### ur filter could be like this

```
public class JWTFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

private TokenProvider tokenProvider;

public JWTFilter(TokenProvider tokenProvider) {
    this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    String jwt = resolveToken(httpServletRequest);
    if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && this.tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
        Authentication authentication = this.tokenProvider.getAuthentication(jwt);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
}

private String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest request){
    String bearerToken1 = RequestUtil.getTokenFromHeader(request);
    if (bearerToken1 != null) return bearerToken1;
    String jwt = request.getParameter(JWTConfigurer.AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN);
    if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt)) {
        return jwt;
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

#### and u have to change ur userDetailService to spring know how to laod ur user

```
@Component("userDetailsService")
public class DomainUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DomainUserDetailsService.class);

private final UserRepository userRepository;

public DomainUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String login) {
    log.debug("Authenticating {}", login);

    String lowercaseLogin = login.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
    Optional<User> userByLoginFromDatabase = userRepository.findOneWithRolesByLogin(lowercaseLogin);
    return userByLoginFromDatabase.map(user -> new MyUserDetails(user))
        .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " was not found in the database"));

}

}
```

Comment: There’s one other thing though, do I have to create another class to implement UserDetails interface? Or can I use the existing model that I created for the database mapping?

Comment: yes u have to create another class.this is diffrent from database model and spring.

Comment: Okay thankyou! & btw your code example has only one filter class, does it do both authentication and authorization tasks?

Comment: for authorization u have to use spring security annotaion and other config.

Comment: with spring security u can config what u want but its not simple.i think u want impl ur authorization. to do that u have to get current user and get current authorization and check that in method u want. if current user dont access to method u have throw exception

Comment: SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() this line get u current userDetail service that have current user authorization list u can check with this list

Comment: All these code examples are for spring security 4, spring security 5 has a built in jwt filter. So please go back to the documentation an learn before posting outdated code.