# What is the sequence of calls when we hit a secured API in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to learning spring.
There are not many resources i could find which explain the sequence of events as to what happens when we hit a secured API in spring.

Consider the following scenario:

I want to enable the user to login by hitting a /authenticate endpoint.

In this case i could see several different classes being involved:

1) WebSecurityConfigAdapter(Which allows us to specify security and which roles can access a particular endpoint)

2) OncePerRequestFilter class(Which intercepts every request, verifies it and sets the current authenticated principal in the context)

3) AuthenticationProvider class

4) Abstract Authentication token class

When and where are these classes called during the lifecycle of an api call.Could someone please help me understand or point me to a resource which clearly explains it from a sequence perspective

Comment: Spring has [excellent documentation](https://spring.io/docs) you can refer to, as well as individual classes' javadocs. Unless you can make this question less broad, you should keep reading those some more.

Comment: Thanks for the link, will check it out

Comment: @Electroenthusiast You asked a question but not given feedback for answer. I tried to answer canonicallly not targeting only your doubts but considering future visitors also. Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Spring security is a filter based framework, it plants a WALL(HttpFireWall) before your application in terms of proxy filters or spring managed beans. Your request has to pass through multiple filters to reach your API.

#### Sequence of execution in Spring Security

1. **`WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter`** Provides integration between the SecurityContext and Spring Web's WebAsyncManager.
2. **`SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`** This filter will only execute once per request, Populates the SecurityContextHolder with information obtained from the configured SecurityContextRepository prior to the request and stores it back in the repository once the request has completed and clearing the context holder.
   *Request is checked for existing session. If new request, SecurityContext will be created else if request has session then existing security-context will be obtained from respository*.
3. **`HeaderWriterFilter`** Filter implementation to add headers to the current response.
4. **`LogoutFilter`** If request url is `/logout`(for default configuration) or if request url mathces `RequestMatcher` configured in `LogoutConfigurer` then

   - clears security context.
   - invalidates the session
   - deletes all the cookies with cookie names configured in `LogoutConfigurer`
   - Redirects to default logout success url  `/` or logout success url configured or invokes logoutSuccessHandler configured.
5. **`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`**

   - For any request url other than loginProcessingUrl this filter will not process further but filter chain just continues.
   - If requested URL is matches(must be `HTTP POST`) default `/login` or matches `.loginProcessingUrl()` configured in `FormLoginConfigurer` then `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` attempts authentication.
   - default login form parameters are username and password, can be overridden by `usernameParameter(String)`, `passwordParameter(String)`.
   - setting `.loginPage()` [overrides defaults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apOKt.png)
   - While attempting authentication

     - an [`Authentication`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TQS8.png) object(`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` or any implementation of `Authentication` in case of your custom auth filter) is created.
     - and `authenticationManager.authenticate(authToken)` will be invoked
     - Note that we can configure any number of `AuthenticationProvider` authenticate method tries all auth providers and checks any of the auth provider ***`supports`*** authToken/authentication object, supporting auth provider will be used for authenticating. and returns Authentication object in case of successful authentication else throws `AuthenticationException`.
   - If authentication success session will be created and `authenticationSuccessHandler` will be invoked which redirects to the target url configured(default is `/`)
   - If authentication failed user becomes un-authenticated user and chain continues.
6. `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter`, if you are using it to install a Spring Security aware HttpServletRequestWrapper into your servlet container
7. `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` Detects if there is no Authentication object in the SecurityContextHolder, if no authentication object found, creates `Authentication` object (`AnonymousAuthenticationToken`) with granted authority `ROLE_ANONYMOUS`. Here `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` facilitates identifying un-authenticated users subsequent requests.

**<sub>Debug logs</sub>**

```
DEBUG - /app/admin/app-config at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@aeef7b36: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
```

8. `ExceptionTranslationFilter`, to catch any Spring Security exceptions so that either an HTTP error response can be returned or an appropriate AuthenticationEntryPoint can be launched
9. `FilterSecurityInterceptor`
   There will be `FilterSecurityInterceptor` which comes almost last in the filter chain which gets Authentication object from `SecurityContext` and gets granted authorities list(roles granted) and it will make a decision whether to allow this request to reach the requested resource or not, decision is made by matching with the allowed `AntMatchers` configured in `HttpSecurityConfiguration`.

Consider the exceptions 401-UnAuthorized and 403-Forbidden. These decisions will be done at the last in the filter chain

- Un authenticated user trying to access public resource - **Allowed**
- Un authenticated user trying to access secured resource - **401-UnAuthorized**
- Authenticated user trying to access restricted resource(restricted for his role) - **403-Forbidden**

---

Note: User Request flows not only in above mentioned filters, but there are others filters too not shown here.(`ConcurrentSessionFilter`,`RequestCacheAwareFilter`,`SessionManagementFilter` ...) 
It will be different when you use your custom auth filter instead of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`.
It will be different if you configure JWT auth filter and omit `.formLogin() i.e, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` it will become entirely different case.

---

Just For reference. Filters in spring-web and spring-security
Note: **refer package name in pic**, as there are some other filters from orm and my custom implemented filter.
[image]

> [From Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/HttpSecurityBuilder.html#addFilter-javax.servlet.Filter-) ordering of filters is given as
>
> - ChannelProcessingFilter
> - ConcurrentSessionFilter
> - SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
> - LogoutFilter
> - X509AuthenticationFilter
> - AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter
> - CasAuthenticationFilter
> - UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
> - ConcurrentSessionFilter
> - OpenIDAuthenticationFilter
> - DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter
> - DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter
> - ConcurrentSessionFilter
> - DigestAuthenticationFilter
> - BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter
> - BasicAuthenticationFilter
> - RequestCacheAwareFilter
> - SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
> - JaasApiIntegrationFilter
> - RememberMeAuthenticationFilter
> - AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
> - SessionManagementFilter
> - ExceptionTranslationFilter
> - FilterSecurityInterceptor
> - SwitchUserFilter

You can also refer
[most common way to authenticate a modern web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58404641/2825798) 
[difference between authentication and authorization in context of Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58352649/2825798)