# In Spring-boot, which will execute first among HandlerInterceptor, user-defined filters, and spring-security filters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm new to Spring Security and while learning, I came to know that Spring Security is internally a group of filters. Here I got a bit confused that by default, in what order the `HandlerInterceptor`, user-defined filters and Security filters get executed?

I tried searching internet but all are talking about the differences among these filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Spring-Security-Filters`, `User-defined-Filters`, `HandlerInterceptor` let me put these 3 in other way

**Filters:** `Spring-Security-Filters` and  `User-defined-Filters`
**Mechanism after DispatherServlet:** `HandlerInterceptor` 
<sup>(as shown in below pic)</sup>
[image]

As `HandlerInterceptor` comes after `DispatcherServlet`, **As filters are always processed before reaching servlet** confidently i can tell **`HandlerInterceptor` comes last**.

Now order of `Spring-Security-Filters` vs `User-defined-Filters`
If you use traditional spring-mvc (not spring boot) where you can use xml or java based configuration. You can achieve any order for user defined filter. Either you can place after spring security(springSecurityFilterChain) or before as given below.

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>sessionLastAccessTimeUpdateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.pvn.mvctiles.configuration.SessionLastAccessTimeUpdateFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sessionLastAccessTimeUpdateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Here in above example sessionLastAccessTimeUpdateFilter order is before springSecurityFilterChain sessionLastAccessTimeUpdateFilter executes first. You can change order if you need. The equivalent java configuration is given below.

```java
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
{
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException
    {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);

        servletContext.addFilter("sessionLastAccessTimeUpdateFilter", new SessionLastAccessTimeUpdateFilter())
        .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");

        servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"))
        .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
    }
}
```

But spring boot is different and imposes lot of restrictions compared to traditional spring approach. Spring boot will not support web.xml and filter registration is allowed only through `FilterRegistrationBean` but here registered filters comes after `FilterChainProxy`.

But spring security has provided provision to add filter in between spring security filters through [`.addFilterBefore()` and `.addFilterAfter()`](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-javaconfig-build/1.0.0.M1/api-reference/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html)

Note that spring security has many proxy filters or spring managed beans those filters have specific order. If you implement a filter by creating sub class for `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` then that custom filter order will be same as order defined for `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`

Finally, HandlerInterceptor mechanism comes last, but spring security filters and user defined filters can come in any order and it depends on your configuration.

To have rough idea of these filters execution you can refer [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58580849/2825798)

Answer (score -1):

Spring Security filters (i.e `FilterChainProxy`) should execute first as the point of its existence is to protect all the URL access , so it makes sense that it should execute first to ensure the request has enough permission before executing other filters.

`HandlerInterceptor` is not the Servlet `Filter` but one of the feature of Spring MVC. Think that it is just some codes inside the Spring MVC Servlet (i.e `DispatcherServlet`). As the [`Filter` is executed before `Servlet`](http://otndnld.oracle.co.jp/document/products/as10g/101300/B25221_03/web.1013/b14426/filters.htm#i1000029) , that means if any other user-defined filter is defined *(I assume the user-defined filter you mean is the  Servlet `Filter` registered normally in `web.xml` or something equivalent )*, it will execute before `HandlerInterceptor`.

To summarise , they should execute in the following orders:

1. Spring Security filters
2. User-defined filters
3. HandlerInterceptor

Comment: I think you have not considered addFilterBefore, handlerInterceptor comes last, but user defined filters can be anywhere.

Comment: Because I have no ideas what does user defined filter that the OP means , so that 's why I assume it is a normal Servlet Filter registered in web.xml or something equivalent