# Spring Security HttpSecurity config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I try to understand how the RequestMatcher, AntMatcher and so on are working. I read some posts and understand the basics. Actually I have this simple basic config:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.requestMatchers() //1
        .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize") //2
        .and() //3
        .authorizeRequests() //4
        .anyRequest() //5
        .authenticated() //6;
```

I really dont understand the points 1,2 and 3. From my understanding this means requests of `/login` and `/oauth/authorize` are mapped and should be authorized requests. All other requests needs a authenticatoin.

Means for an endpoint `/user/me` I have to be authenticated because its ruled by point 5 and 6? 
The call to this endpoint is working for me.

In my ohter config I try a different approach:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { // @formatter:off
      http
       .authorizeRequests() //1
        .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/img/**").permitAll() //2
        .anyRequest() //3
        .authenticated() //4
```

From my point of view, this should be the same logic than the first config. But actually the endpoint `/user/me` is not accessable any more.

I would really appreciated for a clarification

---

**Update 1:**

This is my config now:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { // @formatter:off
    http
        .requestMatchers()
           .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/oauth/authorize", 
               "/main", "/logout-success", "/single-logout",
               "/password_forgotten", "/enter_new_password", "/img/**",
               "/logout", "/access_denied")
            .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/img/**", "/logout-success", "/password_forgotten",
                    "/enter_new_password", "/access_denied").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(SecurityUtils::isFrameworkInternalRequest).permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/main")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout-success")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/access_denied")
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"))
            .and().csrf().disable();
```

and if I enter URL `\user\me` as a not authenticated user I get a 401 and this message:

```
<oauth>
<error_description>
Vollständige Authentifikation wird benötigt um auf diese Resource zuzugreifen
</error_description>
<error>unauthorized</error>
</oauth>
```

Which is ok, but means any ohter SecurityFilterChain takes place for this URL, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`requestMatchers()` configures if an URL will be processed by that `SecurityFilterChain`. So if an URL does not match it , the whole `SecurityFilterChain` will be skipped which means Spring Security will not handle this URL after that. If you do not configure it , the default is to match all URLs.

The `authorizeRequests()` configures the authorisation stuff for an URL such as things like if it requires to be authenticated or if only certain roles can access it etc. It only has effect for those URLs that are processed by that SecurityFilterChain (i.e. Those URLs that are matched by `requestMatchers()`)

So , back to your 1st example:

```java
  http.requestMatchers() //1
        .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize") //2
        .and() //3
        .authorizeRequests() //4
        .anyRequest() //5
        .authenticated() //6;
```

It means this SecurityFilterChain will only has effect on `/login` and `/oauth/authorize`. Both URLs are required to be authenticated. All other URLs will not handled by this SecurityFilterChain. So whether `/user/me` is required to be authenticated or not is nothing to do with Spring Security.

```java
http
       .authorizeRequests() //1
        .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/img/**").permitAll() //2
        .anyRequest() //3
        .authenticated() //4
```

It means all URLs will be handled by this SecurityFilterChain (Default value of `requestMatchers()`). `/login` , `/oauth/authorize` and `/img/**` does not need any authorisation. Other URLs are required to be authenticated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification. For example 1 it means `authorizeRequests()` and `anyRequest()` just belong to the defined antMatchers before and does not affect other urls. Means also `/login` needs an authentication. So if I enter this URL the first time spring automatically makes me an AnonymousUser until I really make my authenticaton, right? The reason why `/user/me` comes in place is that this resource is really secured if I am not authorized (in example 1). So there must be another securityFilterChain which checks this url, right?

Comment: Yes. You are right. It is possible that `/user/me` is processed by another `securityFilterChain` . I suggest you to enable the debug mode by `@EnableWebSecurity(debug=true)`  and set the log level of the security security to debug (`logging.level.org.springframework.security.web=DEBUG`) . It will then print the info of the `securityFilterChain` that is used to process an URL request such that you can check if there are any differences between `/user/me` and other URLs

Answer (score 3):

Your first configuration
**.requestMtchers() //1**

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.requestMatchers() //1
        .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize") //2
        .and() //3
        .authorizeRequests() //4
        .anyRequest() //5
        .authenticated() //6;
```

Let me explain your **`.authorizeRequests()` //4**

`http.authorizeRequests()` It's a wild card(`/**`)(just like filter allows every request)
HttpSecurity configuration will consider only requests with these pattern
here you can say

```java
http.authorizeRequests()
//is nothing but equals to
http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests();
//and also equals to
http.requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/**")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
```

if you configure like below

```
http.antMatcher("/api/**").authorizeRequests();
```

Rest of the configuration(`.hasRole()`, `.hasAnyRole`, `.authenticated()` or `.authenticated()`) will only get consulted if incoming request uri matches the configured antmatcher(`/api/**`)

Consider you have multiple URL's(different pattern) needs to be configured then you can't use simply one antMatcher. You need multiple then you should use requestMatcher as below

```java
http.requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/api/**", "employee/**", "/customer/**")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
```

**.antMatchers() //2**
Used for configuring `RequestMatcherConfigurer` return type of `.requestMatchers()`
or also 
Used for configuring `ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry` return type of `.authorizeRequests()`

**.and() //3**

> Return the HttpSecurity for further customizations

**.anyRequest() //5**

> The object that is chained after creating the RequestMatcher

All request matches configured request matcher pattern

**.authenticated() //6**
Below configuration is self explainatory

```
.antMatchers("/app/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
//or
.antMatchers("/app/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
//or
.antMatchers("/app/admin/**").authenticated()
//or
.antMatchers("/app/admin/**").permitAll()
```

This is rough idea about antMatchers, authorizeRequests, and authenticated. You can refer my answer in this link [for sequence of execution in spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58580849/2825798)