# Spring Security not intercepting correctly?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have Spring Boot configuration which looks something like this:

```
http
    .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
    .addFilterBefore( new Filter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .csrf().disable() // Disabled, cause enabling it will cause sessions
    .headers()
        .frameOptions()
        .sameOrigin()
        .addHeaderWriter(new XXssProtectionHeaderWriter())
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/app/**", "/rest/**").hasAuthority(DefaultPrivileges.ACCESS_TASK)
        .anyRequest().permitAll();
```

My understanding was only the requests which start with `/app` or `/rest` will be intercepted by my custom filter but it turns out the requests to the root (`http://localhost:8080/context/`) are also intercepted.

I have multiple configurations for Spring Security the other configuration looks like this:

```
http
    .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
    .csrf().disable();

if (taskAppProperties.isRestEnabled()) {
    if (restAppProperties.isVerifyRestApiPrivilege()) {
        http
            .antMatcher("/*-api/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*-api/**").hasAuthority(DefaultPrivileges.ACCESS_REST_API)
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
    } else {
        http
            .antMatcher("/*-api/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*-api/**").authenticated()
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
} else {
    http
        .antMatcher("/*-api/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/*-api/**").denyAll();
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: `http.authorizeRequests()` means  `http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()`. It means all urls will be intercepted and verified for authorization. If you want your http security configuration to be limited for very few set of URL's then you should go for `http.antMatcher("/app/**", "/rest/**").authorizeRequests()` or in advanced you can choose requestMatcher as given in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58755858/2825798)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realize this is a bit confusing, but there are actually *two* `antMatchers` methods, one that branches from `authorizedRequests` and another that branches from `requestMatchers`.

Let's look at the following declaration:

```java
http
    .requestMatchers()
        .antMatchers("/app/**", "/api/**")
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("...").authenticated()
    ...
```

The `requestMatchers()` DSL is where you describe the endpoints that matter to that instance of the Spring Security filter chain. So, this filter chain will only engage for URIs that start with `/app` or `/api`.

Let's take a look at another one:

```java
http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/app/**", "/api/**")
    .authenticated();
```

While this may appear to be doing the same thing, it isn't. That's because you are calling the `antMatchers` method that belongs to `authorizeRequests()`.

This is why [indentation is important with the Spring Security DSL](https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/11/spring-security-java-config-preview-readability/). Because there's a hierarchy in the DSL, then you want to indent, just like you want to indent inside your `if` statements.

In Spring Security 5.2, this is simplified a bit with the new lambda DSL:

```java
http
    .requestMatchers(r -> r.antMatchers("/app/**", "/api/**"))
    .authorizeRequests(a -> a.antMatchers("...").authenticated());
```

Answer (score 0):

`HttpSecurity.authorizeRequests` - returns `ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry` where we are setting Matchers and Roles condition, which will be added using method `ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry.getRegistry` and if you check other usage of this method only at `permitAll` stub where actual authentication happens.

[image]

The filter we add using `HttpSecurity.addFilterBefore` will not check any Request matching. If you need, you can do one more check in your custom filter to avoid other URIs

```
http
  .sessionManagement()
  .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
  .and()
  .addFilterAfter( new Filter() {
      @Override
      public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

      }

      @Override
      public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
          HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = ((HttpServletRequest) request);
          if(httpServletRequest.getRequestURI().startsWith("/app/") || httpServletRequest.getRequestURI().startsWith("/rest/")) {
              // Do you secured filter computations

          } 
          chain.doFilter(request, response);
      }

      @Override
      public void destroy() {

      }}, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
  .csrf()
  .disable() // Disabled, cause enabling it will cause sessions
  .headers()
  .frameOptions()
  .sameOrigin()
  .addHeaderWriter(new XXssProtectionHeaderWriter())
  .and()
  .authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/app/**", "/rest/**")
  .hasAuthority(DefaultPrivileges.ACCESS_TASK)
  .anyRequest()
  .permitAll();
```