# c.e.security.jwt.AuthEntryPointJwt : Unauthorized error: Full authentication is required to access this resource

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, swagger, springdoc

`application.properties`

```
server.port=8088

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/tenant_single_db
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

# Application properties
# https://passwordsgenerator.net/
app.jwtSecret=pXpYPZ8d8FQv7UDepXpYPZ8d8FQv7UDepXpYPZ8d8FQv7UDepXpYPZ8d8FQv7UDepXpYPZ8d8FQv7UDepXpYPZ8d8FQv7UDe
app.jwtExpirationMs=86400000

# swagger-ui custom path. Run ok.
# http://localhost:8088/swagger-ui/index.html
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html
springdoc.packagesToScan=com.example.controller, com.example.controllers
```

config

```java
package com.example.security;

import com.example.security.jwt.AuthEntryPointJwt;
import com.example.security.jwt.AuthTokenFilter;
import com.example.security.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        // securedEnabled = true,
        // jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    // Nếu id gửi lên != id của tenant của user đó trong database, thì không cho đi tiếp.
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**", "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        //;

       // .addFilterAfter(new CustomFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class); // VyDN 2022_07_22 // https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter
    }

}

// Add filter before, after: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59000469
```

log

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.1.1\bin\java.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:60285,suspend=y,server=n -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -javaagent:C:\Users\donhu\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.1\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "D:\github\spring-jwt\target\classes;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.7.1\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.7.1\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.7\aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.7.1\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\4.0.3\HikariCP-4.0.3.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.3.21\spring-jdbc-5.3.21.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.6.9.Final\hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.3.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.12.11\byte-buddy-1.12.11.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.4.2.Final\jandex-2.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.2.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.6\jaxb-runtime-2.3.6.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.6\txw2-2.3.6.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.12\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.12.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\com\sun\activation\jakarta.activation\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.7.1\spring-data-jpa-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.7.1\spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.3.21\spring-orm-5.3.21.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.21\spring-context-5.3.21.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.3.21\spring-tx-5.3.21.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.21\spring-beans-5.3.21.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.36\slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.3.21\spring-aspects-5.3.21.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-security\2.7.1\spring-boot-starter-security-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.7.1\spring-boot-starter-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.7.1\spring-boot-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.7.1\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.7.1\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.11\logback-classic-1.2.11.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.11\logback-core-1.2.11.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.17.2\log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.2.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.17.2\log4j-api-2.17.2.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.36\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.30\snakeyaml-1.30.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.21\spring-aop-5.3.21.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\5.7.2\spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\5.7.2\spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.21\spring-expression-5.3.21.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-validation\2.7.1\spring-boot-starter-validation-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.64\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.64.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.2.3.Final\hibernate-validator-6.2.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\jakarta\validation\jakarta.validation-api\2.0.2\jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.7.1\spring-boot-starter-web-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.7.1\spring-boot-starter-json-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.13.3\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.13.3\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.13.3\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.7.1\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.64\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.64\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.64.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.21\spring-web-5.3.21.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.21\spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\io\jsonwebtoken\jjwt-api\0.11.5\jjwt-api-0.11.5.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\io\jsonwebtoken\jjwt-impl\0.11.5\jjwt-impl-0.11.5.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\io\jsonwebtoken\jjwt-jackson\0.11.5\jjwt-jackson-0.11.5.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.13.3\jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.13.3\jackson-annotations-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\4.0.0\jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.0.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.3.1\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\javax\activation\javax.activation-api\1.2.0\javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-hibernate5\2.13.3\jackson-datatype-hibernate5-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\javax\transaction\javax.transaction-api\1.3\javax.transaction-api-1.3.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.13.3\jackson-core-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\postgresql\postgresql\42.3.6\postgresql-42.3.6.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-qual\3.5.0\checker-qual-3.5.0.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springdoc\springdoc-openapi-ui\1.6.9\springdoc-openapi-ui-1.6.9.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springdoc\springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core\1.6.9\springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core-1.6.9.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\webjars\swagger-ui\4.11.1\swagger-ui-4.11.1.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\webjars\webjars-locator-core\0.50\webjars-locator-core-0.50.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\io\github\classgraph\classgraph\4.8.147\classgraph-4.8.147.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springdoc\springdoc-openapi-security\1.6.9\springdoc-openapi-security-1.6.9.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springdoc\springdoc-openapi-common\1.6.9\springdoc-openapi-common-1.6.9.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\io\swagger\core\v3\swagger-core\2.2.0\swagger-core-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.12.0\commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\dataformat\jackson-dataformat-yaml\2.13.3\jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\io\swagger\core\v3\swagger-annotations\2.2.0\swagger-annotations-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\io\swagger\core\v3\swagger-models\2.2.0\swagger-models-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\5.7.2\spring-security-core-5.7.2.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-crypto\5.7.2\spring-security-crypto-5.7.2.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.21\spring-core-5.3.21.jar;C:\Users\donhu\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.21\spring-jcl-5.3.21.jar;D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.example.SpringApplication
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:60285', transport: 'socket'

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.1)

2022-07-21 21:40:02.090  INFO 16836 --- [           main] com.example.SpringApplication            : Starting SpringApplication using Java 18.0.1.1 on vypc with PID 16836 (D:\github\spring-jwt\target\classes started by donhu in D:\github\spring-jwt)
2022-07-21 21:40:02.092  INFO 16836 --- [           main] com.example.SpringApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-07-21 21:40:02.679  INFO 16836 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-07-21 21:40:02.730  INFO 16836 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 46 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-07-21 21:40:03.058  INFO 16836 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8088 (http)
2022-07-21 21:40:03.064  INFO 16836 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-07-21 21:40:03.064  INFO 16836 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.64]
2022-07-21 21:40:03.147  INFO 16836 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-07-21 21:40:03.147  INFO 16836 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1028 ms
2022-07-21 21:40:03.247  WARN 16836 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-07-21 21:40:03.313  INFO 16836 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-07-21 21:40:03.341  INFO 16836 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.9.Final
2022-07-21 21:40:03.424  INFO 16836 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-07-21 21:40:03.515  INFO 16836 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-07-21 21:40:03.580  INFO 16836 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-07-21 21:40:03.592  INFO 16836 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2022-07-21 21:40:07.485  INFO 16836 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-07-21 21:40:07.492  INFO 16836 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-07-21 21:40:08.165  INFO 16836 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@72ad1402, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@621ae2e7, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@3cef755e, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@21275d4a, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@683eef1e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@16e578fc, com.example.security.jwt.AuthTokenFilter@3346245e, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7a1768bd, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@65e62ae8, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@525284af, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@70cbce67, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@1addcf78, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@3c87f534]
2022-07-21 21:40:08.371  INFO 16836 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8088 (http) with context path ''
2022-07-21 21:40:08.380  INFO 16836 --- [           main] com.example.SpringApplication            : Started SpringApplication in 6.518 seconds (JVM running for 7.082)
2022-07-21 21:40:09.834  INFO 16836 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-07-21 21:40:09.834  INFO 16836 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-07-21 21:40:09.835  INFO 16836 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2022-07-21 21:40:10.000 ERROR 16836 --- [nio-8088-exec-7] c.e.security.jwt.AuthEntryPointJwt       : Unauthorized error: Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

[image]

Go to URL http://localhost:8088/swagger-ui/index.html

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is mostly correct, your swagger page loads properly except that when it tries to retrieve the swagger config and api-docs via its ajax call it fails to do so because it's under security's control.

Look at your dev tools and watch the network traffic; you'll probably see a couple of requests like this:

`/v3/api-docs` or `/v3/api-docs/swagger-config`

So, adding `/v3/api-docs/**` to your included `permitAll()` should do the trick.

```
.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs").permitAll()
```