# How to fix error of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter when upgrade to Spring Boot 3.0.0?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have code work ok with Spring 2.x . Source code of Spring 2.x

[image]

File `CustomFilter.java`

```java
package com.example.security;

import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletResponse;
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CustomFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

File `AuthEntryPointJwt.java`

```java
package com.example.security.jwt;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
public class AuthEntryPointJwt implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthEntryPointJwt.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        logger.error("Unauthorized error: {}", authException.getMessage());
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        final Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<>();
        body.put("status", HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        body.put("error", "Unauthorized");
        body.put("message", authException.getMessage());
        body.put("path", request.getServletPath());
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), body);
    }

}
```

File `AuthTokenFilter.java`

```java
package com.example.security.jwt;

import com.example.security.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import java.io.IOException;

public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthTokenFilter.class);

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = parseJwt(request);
            if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
                String username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);
                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return headerAuth.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

File `JwtUtils.java`

```java
package com.example.security.jwt;

import com.example.security.services.UserDetailsImpl;
import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.MalformedJwtException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.UnsupportedJwtException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Date;

@Component
public class JwtUtils {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtUtils.class);

    @Value("${app.jwtSecret}")
    private String jwtSecret;

    @Value("${app.jwtExpirationMs}")
    private int jwtExpirationMs;

    public String generateJwtToken(Authentication authentication) {
        UserDetailsImpl userPrincipal = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
        return Jwts.builder().setSubject((userPrincipal.getUsername())).setIssuedAt(new Date()).setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + jwtExpirationMs)).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret).compact();
    }

    public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }

    public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT signature: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            logger.error("JWT token is expired: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("JWT token is unsupported: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("JWT claims string is empty: {}", e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

File `UserDetailsImpl.java`

```java
package com.example.security.services;

import com.example.models.User;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String email;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public UserDetailsImpl(Long id, String username, String email, String password, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

    public static UserDetailsImpl build(User user) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getRoles().stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName().name())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new UserDetailsImpl(user.getId(), user.getUsername(), user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;
        UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, user.id);
    }

}
```

File `UserDetailsServiceImpl.java`

```java
package com.example.security.services;

import com.example.models.User;
import com.example.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

// Original.
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found with username: " + username));
        return UserDetailsImpl.build(user);
    }

}
```

file `WebSecurityConfig.java`

```java
package com.example.security;

import com.example.security.jwt.AuthEntryPointJwt;
import com.example.security.jwt.AuthTokenFilter;
import com.example.security.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        // securedEnabled = true,
        // jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    // Nếu id gửi lên != id của tenant của user đó trong database, thì không cho đi tiếp.
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                //.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**", "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()

                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/app/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        //;

        // .addFilterAfter(new CustomFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class); // VyDN 2022_07_22 // https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter
    }

}

// Add filter before, after: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59000469
```

Now, I am using Java / JDK 19, Spring Boot 3.0.0 . After upgrade to Spring Boot 3.0.0 , it causes syntax error. [image]

[image]

How to fix error of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` when upgrade to Spring Boot 3.0.0? Specific to my configuration. Please guide me rewrite file `WebSecurityConfig.java`

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html#_stop_using_websecurityconfigureradapter

Comment: How to migration this config `.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()` in Spring Boot 3?

Comment: That topic is also covered on the same page linked above under [Use the new requestMatchers methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html#use-new-requestmatchers).

Comment: We use `.requestMatchers`

Answer (score 9):

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated and should use component-based security configuration. You'll have to create a SecurityFilterChain bean for HTTPSecurity and shouldn't extend **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** as other answer suggested. Please refer **https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter** for more details.

Answer (score 2):

replace `.antMatchers -> .requestMatchers` (it will work in spring 3.0.0 )

Answer (score 1):

On Spring Boot 3 `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated. So in your case the `WebSecurityConfig` class should not extend any class and most be implemented by itself. You can implement the `userDetailsService` by yourself as a `@Bean` and also set the `AuthenticationManager`, not just return the super.
I had the same problem and my solution was just to add `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`
before the `@Configuration` annotation in the class.