# Authentication with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have some confusion when working with authentication in spring security. There are two ways of authentication.

> 1. By overriding configure method
> 2. By implementing bean instance for AuthenticationProvider

I need to know what is the difference between them and the pros and cons of using each.

1.

```java
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {    
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder getBCryptPasswordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

2. 

```java
@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
     DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider=new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
     daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
     daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
     return daoAuthenticationProvider;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you are not sure of the spring security filter chain, see this answer. [How Spring Security Filter Chain works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480102/how-spring-security-filter-chain-works)
- Here is a screenshot I recently took when I was setting up demo ldap + in-memory auth.

  [image]
- As you can see, in the end, we want a type of `AuthenticationFilter` in our spring security filter chain. That filter is responsible for receiving the login request and decide the if authentication successful or not.
- `AuthenticationFilter` has a reference to `AuthenticationManger` and `AuthenticationManger` implementation (which is called `ProviderManager`) does not do authentication directly. Instead `AuthenticationManger` implementations can have a list of   `AuthenticationProvider`s and depend on the type authentication request, it asks the corresponding `AuthenticationProvider` in its list do the authentication.
- `AuthenticationFilter` delegates to `AuthenticationManger` (.ie `ProviderManager`) which in turn delegates to `one` of  `AuthenticationProvider`
- So here is sample. Just for demo purpose, I am duplicating your  `authenticationProvider()` definition and see how the `AuthenticationManger` .ie `ProviderManager` looks

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider1())
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider2());
    }

    @Bean("my-auth-provider-1")
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider1(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider=new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean("my-auth-provider-2")
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider2(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        return provider;
    }
```

[image]

**Note**

I have simplified a bit here. Actually `ProviderManager` can have parent too. But effectively it has a list of providers. See https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture

[image]