# Controlling the order of non-security Filters in a Spring Boot app using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-filter

Java + Spring Boot here. I am building a RESTful web service that uses Spring Security for authentication/authorization.

Spring Security ships with a vast array of its own flexible and configurable Filters. My service has a need to define several of its own Filters, however:

- they have absolutely **nothing** to do with security, and as such, shouldn't require any configuration within Spring Security's API; and
- I do want them to be invoked *after* Spring Security has already allowed requests through all of its own security Filters; meaning these "non-security" Filters only get invoked if Spring Security has allowed the request through, ahead of time

I see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480102/how-spring-security-filter-chain-works) as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480102/how-spring-security-filter-chain-works) but these both involve configuring *other* custom security Filters to work with Spring Security's built-in Filters. How can I configure Spring Boot to "position" my non-security Filters "after" (further down the filter chain) from Spring Security? And how can I control the order of those Filters once I do?

Comment: here is the complete filter list https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html#servlet-security-filters and you use the function `httpSecurity.addFilterAfter` https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#addFilterAfter(javax.servlet.Filter,java.lang.Class) after the last one

Comment: You mean...I need to use Spring Security to configure the ordering of **non-security** filters? That doesn't make sense! What would I use to configure filter order if I wasn't using Spring Security?!

Comment: Then you would use what is proposed as the answer

Comment: Thanks, that answer is close but still not quite what I'm looking for, please see my comment under that question -- I have the same question for you!

Comment: why not just read the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html that he so kindly linked in his answer?

Comment: Because that documentation doesn't tell me how to avoid ordering collisions with Spring Security filters. I feel like you are rushing through this question and not actually reading it. I have Spring Security filters. I have non-security filters. That have nothing to do with Spring Security. But I need them invoked after the Spring Security filters have a chance to process requests. And I need them to not "collide" with Spring Security filters (by _collide_ I mean: I need to configure them such that they always run after Spring Security filters run). I don't know how else to say this.

Comment: Do you have ordering collisions? Show me code where you have ordering collisions. I expect you to read the docs and then experiment and try for yourself. And we have given you the answer, you either use my way or you use order. And we answer questions for free in our spare time. Remember that, good luck with you problem

Comment: The user whose answer I accepted answered my question. Your method required me to use Spring Security to configure non-security filters, which was not acceptable.  Had I randomly chosen an `@Order` value of `100` then I would have had issues/collisions with Spring Security, at the accepted answer has now steered me clear of that. Also, offering someone a grilled cheese when they state they need a PB&J doesn't help them, at all.

Comment: Remember we answer for free. Never forget that. Good luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may set order of filter using [@Order](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html) annotation. It has default value `Integer.MAX_VALUE` this way your filter will be executed last(lower values have higher priority). Here is an example:

```
@Order
@Component
public class TestFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```

Spring Security is a single physical `Filter` but delegates processing to a chain of internal filters such as: SecurityContextPersistenceFilter, RememberMeAuthenticationFilter, AnonymousAuthenticationFilter, etc. The security filter is installed at a position defined by [SecurityProperties.DEFAULT_FILTER_ORDER](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/SecurityProperties.html#DEFAULT_FILTER_ORDER) which is set to `-100`. So any filter with order higher than `-100` will be executed after FilterChainProxy (concrete class of spring security filter)

For example:

```
@Order(SecurityProperties.DEFAULT_FILTER_ORDER-1)
@Component
public class BeforeSecurityFilter implements Filter
```

Will be executed before security filter and:

```
@Order(SecurityProperties.DEFAULT_FILTER_ORDER+1)
@Component
public class AfterSecurityFilter implements Filter
```

Will be executed after security filter

Comment: Thanks @eparvan (+1) - what values are safe to set for `@Order(value = ???`) so that my non-security filters are guaranteed to be invoked after (again, further down the filter chain) all the Spring Security filters are invoked. That is the essence of this question: how do I order non-security filters to _not_ interfere with Spring Security filters?!

Comment: Did you find a way to set the order to run them as last? I have the same scenario as you.