# How to only check for Authentication by "Bearer" header in Spring Boot using Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to authenticate a server. I want to make sure the user is giving a header key, **I am not checking for login or anything.**

I want the header key to check with my hardcoded one,
If its equal pass it,
Else no

I wrote two filters.

`SecurityConfig.java`

```
package com.company.framework.filter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig{

    @Autowired private AuthFilter filtet;

    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("reaching here3 ");
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/open/**").permitAll()
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(
         (request, response,     authException) ->
                                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Error here")
                    )
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .and()
            .httpBasic().disable();

        http
            .addFilter(filtet);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

`Authfilter.java`

```java
package com.company.framework.filter;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

@Component
public class AuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    
        String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        System.out.println("here ");
        System.out.println(authHeader+"1");
        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.length() == 0 && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            String jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
            System.out.println(authHeader+"2");
            if (jwt == null) {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Invalid JWT Token in Bearer Header");
            } else {
                String rev = "bfrek";
                if (jwt.equals(rev)) {
                    response.setStatus(200);
                } else {
                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Invalid JWT Token");
                }
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

But, after all days of try and error, I am still getting 401 unauthorised.
I have seen articles telling how to connect it with users database but I just want to check for header token and pass it through. (Using filter)

**Edit 1:**
Now after reading many articles and documentation, I understand that there are 15 filters, But how do I make sure that the system just checks for my header key and ignore everything else.

Comment: Your filter needs to be in the right place to be relevant, if other filters before already return a 401, it won't reach your code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480102/how-spring-security-filter-chain-works/58580849#58580849 there should be a `http.addBefore` method where you can set the target and there's an annotation to put on filters iirc.

Comment: You forgot "to `@Bean`" `SecurityFilterChain`!? ...https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/ ..i am not sure, whether it is "mandatory", but sample shows "with bean annotation"..

Comment: Hey xerx, I had add Bean earlier but It was giving me Autowiring error for long time, So i removed it.

Comment: ..sounds suspect/very different .. please re-add `@Bean`, and let's analyse the auto-wiring error!(?) ..[edit]

Comment: This is the error its giving,

Description:

Parameter 0 of method filterChain in com.company.framework.Security.SecurityConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' in your configuration.

Comment: this sounds, like you have a conflicting config!?!? What is `com.company.framework.Security.SecurityConfig` ? In OP, you show: `com.company.framework.filter.SecurityConfig`!!

Answer (score 0):

Seems you missed **overriding the `configure` method of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`** class. This is the main logic to override the default spring security logic. This is the main problem i guess. try to extend that class(**WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**) and override that method(configure) in **SecurityConfig.java**.

```
SecurityConfig.java

package com.company.framework.filter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurer{


    @Autowired private AuthFilter filtet;

    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("reaching here3 ");
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/v1/open/**").permitAll()
         .and()
         .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(
         (request, response,     authException) ->
                                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Error here")
                    )
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .and()
                .httpBasic().disable();

        http.addFilter(filtet);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is the old deprecated way. OP used the new way. See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html